# Try to run 4 threads in one method

Tags: java, multithreading

i try following code to run on 4 parallel threads but it does not work..and i don't know if it is possible to do that. Lokk here:

```
List<MyObject> head = a.subList(0, 2000);
    List<MyObject> body = a.subList(2000, 5000);
    List<MyObject> body2 =  a.subList(5000, 8000);
    List<MyObject> tail = a.subList(8000, a.size());



  //  List<Integer> tail = numbers.subList(4, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) {
        a = head.get(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            b = l.get(j);

            fun1 = curr1;
            fun2 = b.getName();

            int d = dL.execute(fun1,fun2);

            if(d<5){
                int x=a.getName().length();
                int y=b.getName().length();

                if(x<y){
                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                if(y<x){
                    a.setName(b.getName());
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                if(x==y){
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                break;}}}


    for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++) {
        a = body.get(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            b = l.get(j);

            fun1 = curr1;
            fun2 = b.getName();

            int d = dL.execute(fun1,fun2);

            if(d<5){
                int x=a.getName().length();
                int y=b.getName().length();

                if(x<y){
                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                if(y<x){
                    a.setName(b.getName());
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                if(x==y){
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                break;}}}       

    for (int i = 0; i < body2.size(); i++) {
        a = body2.get(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            b = l.get(j);

            fun1 = curr1;
            fun2 = b.getName();

            int d = dL.execute(fun1,fun2);

            if(d<5){
                int x=a.getName().length();
                int y=b.getName().length();

                if(x<y){
                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                if(y<x){
                    a.setName(b.getName());
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                if(x==y){
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                break;}}}

    for (int i = 0; i < tail.size(); i++) {
        a = head.get(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            b = l.get(j);

            fun1 = curr1;
            fun2 = b.getName();

            int d = dL.execute(fun1,fun2);

            if(d<5){
                int x=a.getName().length();
                int y=b.getName().length();

                if(x<y){
                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                if(y<x){
                    a.setName(b.getName());
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                if(x==y){
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                break;}}}
```

what i want is to run these 4 double for loops in 4 different threads to run parallel...is it possible..if yes how to manage this.Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to do this? In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your loops into the run() method of an extended class, MyThread, and creates 4 MyThread instances and get them started.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
      @Override
      public void run(){
          //your code to implement the contents of run() method
      }
 }



public class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
             new MyThread().start()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for this solution...you won't imagine what i tried to do ;-)

Comment: @skiwi agree with you Runnable is better than Thread, if implements Runnable, we can extends other classes

Answer (score 3):

Your 4 code blocks look the same, so the first step would be to extract your algorithm to a method

```
public void algo(List<MyObject> head) {
    for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) {
        a = head.get(i);
       for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            b = l.get(j);

            fun1 = curr1;
            fun2 = b.getName();

            int d = dL.execute(fun1,fun2);

            if(d<5){
                int x=a.getName().length();
                int y=b.getName().length();

                if(x<y){
                    currCDO.add(a);

                }
                if(y<x){
                    a.setName(b.getName());
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                if(x==y){
                    currCDO.add(a);
                }
                break;
           }
        }  
    }  
}
```

Then one possible solution would be to call this for each list:

```
public void createAndRun(final List<MyObject> list) {
   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run(){
          algo(list);
      }

   });
   thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Runnable doesn't need a run method?

Comment: Nice, +1 for using a tidy method that shows how to inject a list.  Oh and please fix the three closing braces.  Seeing }}} makes me sad.